# SQL One to many query in one line

Tags: mysql, one-to-many

I have a table with products, a table with **four** manufacturers and an intermediate table.
I want to export a list of products that may or may not have more than one manufacturer.
I would like to export each product in a line with four columns on the right (one for each manufacturer).

products table

```
|----|------|
| id | name |
|----|------|
| 12 | foo  |
|----|------|
```

product_manufacturer table

```
|----|------------|------------------|---------------------------|
| id | product_id |  manufacturer_id | manufacturer_product_code |
|----|------------|------------------|---------------------------|
| XX |     12     |       ABCD       |          X1X2             |
|----|------------|------------------|---------------------------|
| YY |     12     |       LMKO       |          AAAB             |
|----|------------|------------------|---------------------------|
```

desired result:

```
+------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| name | internal_id | manufacturer1_code | manufacturer2_code | manufacturer3_code | manufacturer4_code |
+------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| foo  |          12 | X1X2               | null               | AAAB               | null               |
+------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

I've tried this:

```
     SELECT p.`name` AS product, p.`id` AS internal_id, 
          (
           SELECT pm.`manufacturer_product_code`
             FROM  `product_manufacturer` pm
            WHERE pm.`manufacturer_id` internal_id 
              AND pm.`manufacturer_id` LIKE 'ABCD'
        ) AS manufacturer1_code,
        (
           SELECT pm.`manufacturer_product_code`
             FROM  `product_manufacturer` pm
            WHERE pm.`manufacturer_id` LIKE internal_id 
              AND pm.`manufacturer_id` LIKE 'CDCD'
       ) AS manufacturer2_code,
          (
           SELECT pm.`manufacturer_product_code`
             FROM  `product_manufacturer` pm
            WHERE pm.`manufacturer_id` LIKE internal_id 
              AND pm.`manufacturer_id` LIKE 'LMKO'
          ) AS manufacturer3_code,
          (
           SELECT pm.`manufacturer_product_code`
             FROM  `product_manufacturer` pm
            WHERE pm.`manufacturer_id` LIKE internal_id 
              AND pm.`manufacturer_id` LIKE 'RSRS'
            ) AS manufacturer4_code
       FROM `product_manufacturer` pm 
 INNER JOIN `products` p 
         ON p.`id`=pm.`product_id`
```

This is returning the first two columns well, but the other four return null.
When I get it to work, I should use `Group by p.name`

What is the correct way? Thanks.

Comment: I recommend to use UNION

Comment: @OmerTekbiyik union will append rows, not columns

Comment: as a side note in your query no need for LIKE, just use = since you are looking for an exact match. LIKE is used to search for something that starts with 'abc%', contains'%abc%' or end with '%abc' where % is a wildcard for any value.

Comment: Why does AAAB  appear as manufacturer3_code rather than manufacturer2_code?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is via row_number simulation

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T,T1;
CREATE TABLE T (ID INT, NAME VARCHAR(10));
CREATE TABLE T1( id varchar(2), product_id int,  manufacturer_id varchar(20), manufacturer_product_code varchar(20));

insert into t values(12,'foo');
insert into t1 values
('XX' ,     12     ,       'ABCD'       ,          'X1X2'),
('YY' ,     12     ,       'LMKO'       ,          'AAAB');

select t.name,t.id,
        max(case when rownumber = 1 then manufacturer_product_code else '' end) man1,
        max(case when rownumber = 2 then manufacturer_product_code else '' end) man2,
        max(case when rownumber = 3 then manufacturer_product_code else '' end) man3,
        max(case when rownumber = 4 then manufacturer_product_code else '' end) man4
from t
join
(
select t1.*,
         if(t1.product_id <> @p,@rn:=1,@rn:=@rn+1) rownumber,
         @p:=t1.product_id p
from t1
cross join (select @rn:=0,@p:=0) r
order by t1.product_id,t1.id
) s
on s.product_id = t.id
group by t.name,t.id;
```

In this query a row number is allocated in the sub query and conditional aggregation is used in the outer query to allocate the manufacturer to a column.

```
+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| name | id   | man1 | man2 | man3 | man4 |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| foo  |   12 | X1X2 | AAAB |      |      |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

If you have version 8 or above you could use row_number window function rather than the simulation using variables in the sub query.

Comment: Thanks. This works with newly created tables like t and t1 but when I do with an existing table it returns an error `Ilegal mezcla de collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) y (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) para operación '<>'`. (illegal collation mix) All my tables and fields use `utf8_general_ci`. I think the error is when creating @p or @rn. I've tried adding `COLLATE utf8_general_ci` to variables with no luck. Any suggestions? (also, for your code to work I had to use lowercase on table names when creating them)